# nuxt build Breaks VueJS Events

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, npm, nuxt.js

I'm running a nuxtjs application in production and it's causing some VueJS functionality to break, particular with DOM events. **However**, development mode works just fine as it should flawlessly, though it is slower than production mode due to the code not being minified and compiled and all that.

- `@click` events do not fire their functionality
- `.prevent` does not prevent anything

Here's my source of an example section that does not work.

The `@click` event calls that change the `view` do not do anything.

Upon hitting enter to fire `v-on:keydown.enter="login"` it does not get prevented and the form gets submitted as a `GET` request to the same page ( the URL shows the `GET` ?variables )

After looking at the HTML code in the browser to see if there's any logged warnings or errors, there's nothing and nothing on the server side logs.

**Plus,** the `<button>` tags that have the `@click` to fire the login or signup methods do not have **any** events on them, basically not doing anything; just HTML.

On my production server after running `nuxt build` by executing `npm run build`, there are **no errors or warnings**.

```html
<template>
<div class='card'>
    <div class='tabs 2-col'>
        <span :class="{active : view != 'signup'}" @click="view = 'login'">
            Login
        </span>
        <span :class="{active : view == 'signup'}" @click="view = 'signup'">
            Sign Up
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class='card-body'>
        <form v-show="view == 'login'" v-on:keydown.enter="login" novalidate>
            <!-- my other html -->
            <button @click.prevent="login">Login</button>
        </form>
        <form v-show="view == 'signup'" v-on:keydown.enter="signup" novalidate>
            <!-- my other html -->
            <button @click.prevent="signup">Sign Up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data : function(){
        return { view : 'login'};
    },
    methods : {
        login: function(){
            // my functionality
        },
        signup:function(){
            // my functionality
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Thank you for any help! I've been banging my head for hours.

Comment: At a basic HTML level you can make the button type “button” then you would not need prevent as then it would not be the default “submit” type as a type has not been provided. Also you would put prevent on the form submit event to prevent the submit event, rather than the button. That being said, button type of button would not trigger a form submit.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky This is true, but VueJS should make it still work like it should and is made to do, along with the `@click` on the `<span>` tags, those do not work on production either.

Comment: Any solution to this yet?

Comment: Hey @christostsang - I believe I still never fixed this. I have switched to a different project, but this particular problem's project is still in Vue2. I would recommend messing around your transpilers, webpack/babel config, and probably consider typescript. 

Good luck to you friend

Comment: Thank you Zac! If i find something i will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

`data` proprerty should be a function that return the object. try to do this:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    view: 'login',
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, that was a typo with my example code that I put together to show just what I need help with, thanks for pointing that out though it's not a solution/answer